# How to make emacs remember my previous search & replace strings

Tags: emacs, replace

I used to have this feature in the past (another Unix computer):

When I search & replace in Emacs (using "Esc %" keys), then when I do it next time, the search and replace strings are remembered from the previous time.

(This was very handy, as if I need to search & replace for same strings in different files, I did not need to re-type the strings over and over for each file).

But now in my Emacs each time I do search & replace no previous strings appear: it is always an empty field.

Comment: What emacs do you use, what version?

Comment: If by *each time* you mean "each time after re-starting Emacs", then look into the [`savehist` mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SaveHist).

Answer (score 0):

Here a conf for savehist

```el
(setq savehist-additional-variables    
        '(search-ring regexp-search-ring compile-history) 
        savehist-file "~/.emacs.d/savehist")
(savehist-mode t)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however when I added it to my .emacs I receive error:An error has occurred while loading `/home/g616735/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: savehist-mode

Comment: save-hist-mode.el come with emacs-22. If your version is older you can use: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/savehist-20+.el